# Bit Planes Slicing_ bitwise and_Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: python, opencv, debugging

I'm trying to perform a Bit Plane Slicing. I use the code shared here, with very few modifications at the end for the export : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41635/bit-plane-slicing-in-python.

It worked fine when I am using a jpeg image at the beginning. However, most of the time, I will be using a tif image. So I modify the first lines and now the code looks like this :

```
img1 = Image.open('C:/Users/Caroline/Documents/Cours/G5/PFE/Donnees/2018_gris.tif') 
img = np.array(img1)

out = []

k=7
# create an image for the k bit plane
plane = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), 2 ** k, np.uint8)
# execute bitwise and operation
res = cv2.bitwise_and(plane, img)
# multiply ones (bit plane sliced) with 255 just for better visualization
x = res * 255
# append to the output list
out.append(x)
outfinal = np.hstack(out)

imgfinale = Image.fromarray(outfinal.astype(np.uint8))
imgfinale.imsave("test1.tif")
```

When I perform it, I have an error message that says

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Caroline\Desktop\BitPlaneSlicing.py", line 24, in <module>
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(plane, img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-4.1.2\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:229: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'`

I checked a few websites, and what I understand from them, it is because the tiff image has more channel than my "plane" image. What I don't get is that my tiff image is a grayscale image without alpha band. For proof, I wrote type(img) and type(plane), and the answer is the same (`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`) and img.shape also give the same result as plane.shape.

In addition, I am new to pyhton, so I am completly lost right now, without any idea of what to even try.

Answer (score 0):

```
img1=cv2.imread('C:/Users/Caroline/Documents/Cours/G5/PFE/Donnees/2018_gris.tif',0) 

img = np.array(img1)

out = []

k=7
# create an image for the k bit plane
plane = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), 2 ** k, np.uint8)
# execute bitwise and operation
res = cv2.bitwise_and(plane, img)
# multiply ones (bit plane sliced) with 255 just for better visualization
x = res * 255
# append to the output list
out.append(x)
outfinal = np.hstack(out)

imgfinale = Image.fromarray(outfinal.astype(np.uint8))
imgfinale.imsave("test1.tif")
```